XQuartz at some point toggles Caps Lock
I am on Monterey 12.7.6 with XQuartz 2.8.5 (xorg-server 21.1.6).
At some point the Caps Lock toggles : With the light on it prints lower case. With the light off it prints uppercase. This happens in a xterm window. If I switch to a mac window, the caps lock corresponds to the light status. Only solution is restart XQuartz.
I would like to know if there is an alternative solution, because I have a few windows open with ssh sessions to remote machines.
Thanks,
Regards
